# Restrict input on NSTextField

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nstextfield

I want to restrict character input on `NSTextField`, i.e. so that disallowed characters aren't even appearing. Most of what I found about this topic were solutions that only validate after text input finished or using `NSFormatter` which still allows the character to appear.

So far I came up with this solution, sub-classing `NSTextField`:

```
class RestrictedTextField : NSTextField
{
    static let VALID_CHARACTERS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'-.& ";

    override func textDidChange(notification:NSNotification)
    {
        for c in stringValue
        {
            if (RestrictedTextField.VALID_CHARACTERS.rangeOfString("\(c)") == nil)
            {
                stringValue = stringValue.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\(c)", withString: "", options: .LiteralSearch, range: nil);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works but isn't really optimal because the textcursor still moves by one space if an invalid character is tried to be entered. I also think the loop shouldn't be necessary so I wonder does somebody know a more elegant solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have complete control with a subclass of `NSFormatter`. I'm not sure why you think you don't.

Override `isPartialStringValid(_:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:)` and implement the desired logic. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFormatter/isPartialStringValid:proposedSelectedRange:originalString:originalSelectedRange:errorDescription:) (with some minor edits by me):

> In a subclass implementation, evaluate [the string pointed to by `*partialStringPtr`] according to the context. Return `YES` if `partialStringPtr` is acceptable and `NO` if `partialStringPtr` is unacceptable. Assign a new string to `partialStringPtr` and a new range to `proposedSelRangePtr` and return `NO` if you want to replace the string and change the selection range.

So, if the user tries to insert disallowed characters, you can either reject their edit in its entirety or modify it to strip those disallowed characters. (Remember that user changes can include pasting, so it's not necessarily just a single typed character.) To reject the change entirely, assign `origString` to `*partialStringPtr` and `origSelRange` to `*proposedSelRangePtr`.

Comment: This works better than using the target/action mechanism as it separates out areas of responsibility. This is key (pun intended) when using Cocoa Bindings, which precludes the target/action mechanism altogether, which means a formatter is your only chance to sanitize the input before it even gets near your model object.